# Vertical line alignment when opening new window in vim

Tags: vim

How do I keep vertical alignment when opening a new window (split) under current one in vim?

When I edit a file, some lines are visible (say 1-20). Once I open another window the visible lines change to something else (say 5-15).  I would like to keep the original window vertically aligned, meaning see lines 1-11 in my example.

Comment: How are you opening the new window? Are you opening a new window via split or vsplit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "vertical alignment" changes because Vim is trying to keep the line that your cursor is currently on in view.  The simplest way to do what you want is just to press <kbd>H</kbd> before you do your split.  <kbd>H</kbd> moves your cursor to the top line of the window, so when you split the viewport won't have to change to keep your cursor in view.

This will move your cursor of course, but you can just hit <kbd>``</kbd> to return to the mark that was set when you pressed <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. The line stays in the view even if alignment is kept. However, as you suggested, pressing `H` (split> `\`\`` solves this issue. How can I do this automatically for every split, especially when the preview windows appears.

Comment: This doesn't work if `&scrolloff` is not zero. I have `&scrolloff = 5`, do you have any other ideas to make it work with `&scrolloff > 0` ? It would be nice to solve.